# Layout issue with CSS and inexperience issue

Tags: html, css, http, web, css-float

I have an issue about HTML and CSS Layout. All i want on my website is a fixed left bar for navigation and a fixed top bar for messages.

I would like both the items to follow when the user scrolls down the page (fixed) but i have an issue telling the CSS i want the top bar to fill up the whole rest of the page width.

Using this HTML :

```
<body>
    <div id="leftbar">
         <img border="0" src="images/somelogo.png">
         <p>leftbartest</p>
         <p></p>
    </div>
    <div id="topbar">
         <p>topbartest</p>
    </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Consider both these CSS examples :

Bar is fixed and stay on page when scroll, but will not fill width and resize when browser window is resized (will fit text size):

```
 body {
    background-color: #A69E40;
 }
 html {
    height: 99%;
    width: 99,8%;
 }
 #leftbar {
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 272px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    border: outset 2px #000000;
 }
 #topbar {
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 268px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 35px;
    z-index: 5;
    border: solid 1px #000000;
 }
```

Bar is not fixed and will not stay on the page when scroll, but will fill width and resize when browser window is resized :

```
body {
   background-color: #A69E40;
}
html {
   height: 99%;
   width: 99,8%;
}
#leftbar {
   position: fixed;
   float: left;
   margin-left: -8px;
   margin-top: -8px;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   width: 272px;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 2;
   border: outset 2px #000000;
}
#topbar {
   margin-left: 268px;
   margin-top: -8px;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   height: 35px;
   z-index: 5;
   border: solid 1px #000000;
}
```

It's meant to create some kind of portal where a table will be embed to the right of the leftbar and under the topbar. All in all the left bar should fit the whole height of the first 272 width pixels, the top bar should fit the whole width of 35 pixels height and the whole rest will be used to drop some tables.

Please detail, i am new to this wonderfull world that is HTML and CSS, and i would like to become solid in this field of modern technology.

Thanks again for reading this and thanks in advances for your brainstorm on my silly beginner problem.

Comment: `width: 99,8%;` is invalid. Did you mean `width: 99.8%;`?

Comment: André, it seems to be working here nonetheless. I removed the ,8 (i don't really care about 2 or 3 pixels) and it didn't change anything. Thanks for the quick reply though

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a CodePen demo.](http://codepen.io/phantomesse/pen/tFEBy)

## Top bar on the top and left bar below it

**HTML**

```
<nav id="left-bar">
  Left bar
</nav>

<header id="top-bar">
  Top Bar
</header>

<article>
  All your content goes here.
</article>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #E4E4C5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  background: #8D2036;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
}

nav {
  padding-top: 35px;
  position: fixed;
  background: #B9D48B;
  width: 272px;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

article {
  padding: 55px 20px 20px 292px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

## Left bar stretching the entire height and top bar next to it

**HTML**

```
<header id="top-bar">
  Top Bar
</header>

<nav id="left-bar">
  Left bar
</nav>

<article>
  All the content goes here...
</article>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #E4E4C5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  padding-left: 272px;
  position: fixed;
  background: #8D2036;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  background: #B9D48B;
  width: 272px;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

article {
  padding: 55px 20px 20px 292px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the fast reply, this seems to be working, however i would like the Left bar to take it's whole height-space and the top bar to be on its side, above the "article" section you did put in there. What do i need to change in order to fix this? Many Thanks again i really appreciate the help man.

Comment: Also i cannot upvote you but i will make sure to comeback when i can.

Comment: @Quardah All you have to do is switch the order of the elements in the HTML and adjust the padding in the CSS. I updated the post with the version you want.

Comment: ohohoh thanks!! This is superbe work! I really appreciate the help man, really. Have a nice day and wish you the best!

Comment: Hi, it's me again. I have one last thing to ask about the example you gave me. Is it possible to tell the top bar to keep a certain distance to its right next to the browser scrollbar? Let's say 5 pixels, the top bar would always resize itself to keep that same distance (until reach either max-width or min-width). Thanks.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. Can you draw a picture?